# How do I get Football Guys website programs (made for MS) to work on Linux?

Tags: linux

I am running Linux Mint on one machine and XP Home on another because I don't know how to get a couple of programs I use when playing Fantasy Football to work on my Linux machine.
I tried Wine and setting up a VirtualBox, but I haven't had any luck.
The programs I want to run from Footballguys.com are Draft Dominator and a program that imports data from myfantasyleague.com  website. 
The programs install fine, but when I try to import the data I get parsing errors and thusly, the programs don't work.So, I have to use the XP machine for those programs.
Any assistance will be very appreciated as I really am beginning to dislike MS and XP.

Comment: Chumley, Footballguys forums is probably better equipped to handle this, http://forums.footballguys.com/forum/

Comment: Just a guess, but your parsing errors could be that Linux isn't interpreting the linefeed/carriage returns correctly in the import file.  It may be trying to parse the whole file as one long line.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have been checking with the forums.footballguys.com/forums and haven't gotten an answer, but I will keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

So, for clarification, did you get a working setup of XP in VirtualBox?  Did you get so you could use the web on it (via your linux host?)  If you got that far, you've probably gotten over the biggest hurdles.

Using a virtual machine (with virtual Box or VMware) is generally the most problem-free way to run windows software on a Linux box.  If the programs work on Wine, you'll have quicker access to them, but VM's generally run more software.